# React Native List item memoization

Tags: react-native, memoization

I am attempting to prevent unnecessary renders of `FlatList` items using `React.memo()` but i have come across some odd behaviour. the call back which provides the previous props and the next props always have the same value, even if they have changed higher up the chain.

```
export default React.memo(PersonCell, (prev, next) => {
  reactotron.log(`prev ${prev.person.name}: is checked${prev.person.isChecked}`)
  reactotron.log(`next ${next.person.name}: is checked${next.person.isChecked}`)
  return prev.person.isChecked === next.person.isChecked
})
```

The chain I have is I use `Realm` with a very simple structure of `{id:number, name:string, isChecked:boolean}` and whenever they tap the cell it will write to realm, at the top level of the app i have a listener to data changes and then set the state to propagate it back down to the list

```
let [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let sub = person$.subscribe({
      next: collection => {
        reactotron.logImportant!(collection)
        setData([...data, ...collection.map(x => x)]);
      },
    });
```

here is the cell code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import realm, { PersonSchema } from "./realm";
import { Person } from "./PersonsList";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";
import reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';

interface Props {
  person: Person
}
const onCheck$ = new Subject<number>();
const PersonCell: React.FC<Props> = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    let sub = onCheck$.subscribe({
      next: x => {
        realm.write(() => {
          let person = realm.objectForPrimaryKey<Person>(PersonSchema.name, x);
          if (!person) return;
          person.isChecked = !person.isChecked;
        });
      },
    });
    return () => sub.unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.person.name}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onCheck$.next(props.person.id)}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: props.person.isChecked
              ? 'rgb(255,1,1)'
              : 'rgb(1,1,255)',
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

PersonCell.whyDidYouRender = true;

// export default React.memo(PersonCell)
export default React.memo(PersonCell, (prev, next) => {
  reactotron.log(`prev ${prev.person.name}: is checked${prev.person.isChecked}`)
  reactotron.log(`next ${next.person.name}: is checked${next.person.isChecked}`)
  return prev.person.isChecked === next.person.isChecked
})
```

Is this expected behaviour or am i doing something wrong?
[Here is a repo](https://github.com/Genhain/FlatList-Item-memoization) of what i am explaining

#### Update

I removed the flatlist and used a basic map and key to generate the list of items and the above issue still appeared of the current props and the passed in props in the `shouldComponentUpdate` and the `React.memo` second parameter are still exactly the same, despite having being changed.

[here is a link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7121) of a guy experiencing something similar

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was due to mutating state in a non react manner. i believed this

```js
let sub = person$.subscribe({
      next: collection => {
        setData(collection.map(x => x));
      },
    });
```

would have been enough to return a new array(since map returns a brand new array) to update the state with the needed change comparison. but apparently you need to do the following.

```
let sub = person$.subscribe({
      next: collection => {
        setData(collection.map(x => x).map(x => _.toPlainObject(x)));
      },
    });
```

i.e make a deep clone of each object returned from realm for it to work correctly...Or perhaps there is an issue with typescript.

If anyone wants to chime in with a more succinct answer you are more than welcome.

Either way the repo has been updated with the changes if anyone wants to have a look at it.